# What is the change in the characterization of the explorers in arctic novels in the past two centuries?

Tags: character-analysis, history-of-literature

Has the general image of explorers or exploring teams in Arctic novels in the 18th, 19th and 20th centuries really changed in essence?

Comment: Hi Ivie and welcome to LitSE. Your question is very broad, can you break it down a little? What triggered your question, are there particular novels and characters that you have in mind? How do you think they are characterised? Are you looking to respond to a claim someone else has made about the topic, if so where might we find their theory? Anything you can share to provoke people's curiosity increases your chances of good answers.